# How to count the amount of keys in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, count

I have the following multidimensional array :

`meeting[$loop->index][person]`are checkboxes
`meeting[$loop->index][date]` are input-fields

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "person" => "Max Example"
    "date" => "10.05"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  6 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  7 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
  8 => array:1 [▼
    "date" => null
  ]
]
```

`person` in this case is a checkbox, so it's only there when it's checked.

Now I want to know, how many persons are 'invited' to the meeting.
So I need to count the amount of `person` (check how often `person` exists).

When only one person is invited I want to display something else than when more people are invited.

I tried it with this:

```
@if ($counts = array_count_values(array_flip(array_column($ticketDaten['hefte'], 'heft'))) == 1)
[...]
```

but if I var_dump it I only get `bool(false)` in both cases (only one person or more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply

```
echo count(array_column($meeting, 'person'));
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/66em5)

Comment: I kind of feel really stupid now for not getting this right. Thanks for the quick answer, it works perfectly fine

Comment: @ofmiceandmoon I use `array_column` *all* the time so it just automatically comes to mind for me...

Comment: then I guess you got a little more experience than me